Expose Angular Kendo UI properties automatically in Storybook
I want to do something similar to what has been achieved in this article (https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-i-built-this-kendoreact-storybook), except using Kendo Angular.
In the article the author describes how she uses Storybook for a design system, but surfaces Kendo components within it. In the linked github she shows how she has created 'wrapper' components that expose the Kendo components and has manually coded all the prop types that a component expects.
Manually coding the prop types (https://github.com/kathryngraysonnanz/kendoreact-storybook/blob/main/src/stories/Button.jsx) looks like it would introduce a maintenance issue as the prop types would need to be updated with each new Kendo release.
Is there a way to automatically surface all the Kendo properties from a given component? Something that inspected the Kendo *.d.ts files and surfaced them in Storybook.
